# Removing deleted files from local

Tags: git, github

I made a git repository with few folders in it. Another contributor deleted one of the directories.

When I tried `git pull origin master` the same folder remains in my system.

How do I remove the folder from my system, without explicitly deleting it?

Comment: are you referring the same branch? if not it may be deleted in the branch your friend deleted but not in yours. verify this.

Comment: Did he pushed his changes (deleted directory)?

Comment: Both were in the master branch.

Comment: did you consider [git clean](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)?

Comment: `git clean` worded. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`git clean`, as [Mykola Gurov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243861/mykola-gurov) suggested in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176282/removing-deleted-files-from-local/75457045#comment54177264_33176282), worked at that time.

Answer (score 0):

`git rm filename` //Files that are removed from system

`git commit -a -m "Removed Deleted Files"` // commit comment

`git push origin branchname` // branchname that you want to push in the system

If this not work than you can hard reset to head....

```
git clean -i -fd
```

-i for interactive

-f for force

-d for directory

-x for ignored files(add if required)